# Current distribution of Hertz dipole NOT in origin of coordinate system

Tags: electromagnetism

Greetings I am having trouble to understand how the distribution should be if the dipole is not at the origin and not along z-axis. For a hertz dipole with length $d<<\lambda$ along z-axis at the origin of coordinate system we can say it has a distribution $\mathbf{J}=I_0 \mathbf{z}_0$. Assume now that the dipole is located along y-axis and at $z=a$, i.e., at $a$ above coordinates origin. How should the current distribution be expressed now? Thank you.

Comment: $\mathbf{J}=I_0 \mathbf{z}_0$ What does the subscript on $\mathbf{z}_0$ mean? If $\mathbf{J}$ is supposed to be a current density and $I_0$ a current (which is the usual meaning of these symbols) then this equation is dimensionally inconsistent.

Comment: $\mathbf{z}_0$ is the unitary vector of z-axis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current distribution is incorrect (even for the origin), both unit-wise (if $I_0$ current) and meaning-wise. You are implying constant current distribution in the whole space.

For point-like z-aligned dipole at position $\mathbf{r}_0$,

$$
\mathbf{J}\left(\mathbf{r}\right)=\mathbf{\hat{z}}I_0 l \delta^{(3)}\left(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_0\right)
$$

where $\delta^{(3)}$ is the delta-function, and $l$ is some sort of a measure of how 'long' the dipole is. Normally you would pack $\mathbf{\hat{z}}I_0 l$=$\mathbf{\dot{p}}$ where $\mathbf{p}$ is the dipole moment. Such 'packing' allows to hide the uncomfortable truth that if $l\to0$, then $I_0\to\infty$ for finite radiated power.

Alternatively you could use something like [Heaviside function - $\mathcal{H}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) and define:

$$
\begin{align}
S\left(\zeta\right)=&\mathcal{H}\left(\zeta+\frac{1}{2}\right) - \mathcal{H}\left(\zeta-\frac{1}{2}\right) \\
\mathbf{J}\left(\mathbf{r}\right)=&\mathbf{\hat{z}}I_0 S\left(\frac{z-z_0}{l}\right) \delta\left(x-x_0\right)\delta\left(y-y_0\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{l}\cdot\left(z-z_0\right)\right) \\
\end{align}
$$

Where $l$ is now a 'proper' length of the dipole and $\cos$ is needed for charge conservation.

I am implying harmonic time-dependence in both cases.

---

Following comments. I think Balanis is not doing the best job in explaing here. Lets back up. In general you are trying to solve

$$
\nabla^2 \mathbf{A}+k^2\mathbf{A}=-\mu\mathbf{J} 
$$

I am assuming only electric and no magnetic current densities here. A solution in case of scattering boundary conditions (basically antenna radiates into free-space and no incoming waves) with no outside excitation is then:

$$
\mathbf{A}\left(\mathbf{r}\right)=\frac{\mu}{4\pi}\int d^3 r' \mathbf{J}\left(\mathbf{r}'\right)\cdot\frac{\exp\left(-jk\left|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'\right|\right)}{\left|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'\right|}
$$

This tells you the 'ammount' of vector potential $\mathbf{A}$ you will see at position $\mathbf{r}$ due to current density at position $\mathbf{r}'$. You have to integrate over the whole space to pick up all the current density. In practice you often define current density to fit inside the volume $V$ in which case you write $\int_V d^3 r'$. This is Balanis's equation Eq. 3-27, but with more explicit notation.

Now you see why spatial dependence of current density matters - it tells you how to limit your volume integral.

Next, how to represent a point-dipole antenna? Balanis talks about end-plates on the wires, Fig. 4-1. This allows him to define a consant current distribution in the wire with finite length. A proper expression for such distribution would be:

$$
\begin{align}
S\left(\zeta\right)=&\mathcal{H}\left(\zeta+\frac{1}{2}\right) - \mathcal{H}\left(\zeta-\frac{1}{2}\right) \\
\mathbf{J}\left(\mathbf{r}\right)=&\mathbf{\hat{z}}I_0 S\left(\frac{z-z_0}{l}\right) \delta\left(x-x_0\right)\delta\left(y-y_0\right) \\
\end{align}
$$

However Balanis does nothing interesting with this finite length of the antenna, so we can take the limit *before* computing the integral. This strays outside your question, so I will leave it for now.

Let us get back to solution and sub in the last current density. Using the properties of the delta-functions:

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbf{A}\left(\mathbf{r}\right)=&\frac{\mu}{4\pi}\int d^3 r' \mathbf{J}\left(\mathbf{r}'\right)\cdot\frac{\exp\left(-jk\left|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'\right|\right)}{\left|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'\right|} \\
=&\mathbf{\hat{z}}\frac{\mu I_0}{4\pi}\int^{z_0+l/2}_{z_0-l/2} dz'\frac{\exp\left(-jk\sqrt{\left(x-x_0\right)^2+\left(y-y_0\right)^2+\left(z-z'\right)^2}\right)}{\sqrt{\left(x-x_0\right)^2+\left(y-y_0\right)^2+\left(z-z'\right)^2}} 
\end{align}
$$

Comment: The current distribution I mentioned is as shown in Balanis "Antenna Theory" book. It wasn't my idea. Are you implying that the aforementioned book has it wrong? Are you familiar with the book?

Comment: If $\mathbf{J}$ is current density, in A/m^2 and $I_0$ is current, in Amps. Then yes, I imply that aforementioned current distribution is wrong, as also noted by @G. Smitth. Balanis is a nice book. Which page is it? Also tell me whether, in your head, current density is everywhere (here, in Antarctica, on Mars etc). If not, then how does your expression ensure it? I think a humbler option is that you my have mis-interpreted a badly-worded passage in the book.

Comment: Section 4.2 page 146. Thanks for the help so far. I also do not understand the primed coordinates. He states that $\mathbf{I}_e(x',y',z')=\mathbf{a}_z I_0$ (with Balanis symbols) with $x'=y'=z'=0$. So how should someone transform this equation if the source is located along y-axis (and not z-axis as in his example) and located at $z'=d/2, y'=0, x'=0$. Earlier in his book he describes that you should use equation 3-49 to calculate the retarded potential A when source not at origin of coordinate system, but I fail to understand how to apply this in the case of hertz dipole.

Comment: @bigboss. Please see edits. Hopefully that helps. By the way, Jackson (Classical Electrodynamics, Chapter 9) treats these things with far more care

Comment: Thank you for your thorough explanation!